# Unable to sign in to Azure from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, azure, authentication

Unable to sign in to Azure from Eclipse(Eclipse IDE 2021‑03).
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tried Below steps:

Downloading the certificate from portal.azure.com.
Added to all the below places, verified the certificate in cacerts using Portecle.
java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\lib\security\cacerts
Java\jre7\lib\security\cacerts
Java\jre1.8.0_241\lib\security\cacerts
Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre\lib\security\cacerts

Eclipse is using the Java C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\jre

Am I missing something here?[image]

Answer (score 0):

This type of issue mostly occurs when a server changes their HTTPS SSL certificate, and our older version of java doesn’t recognize the root certificate authority (CA).

The solution for this question is discussed in the below thread [Resolving javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore)

You can find more information about the error message & cause in the below document https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/217078498-PKIX-path-building-failed-error-message

Comment: I want to know whether the certificate applied to cacerts is valid or not. Should I donwload the certificate from the homepage of portal.azure.com, by clicking on the lock icon in the Google Chrome Browser, or the certificate needs to be downloaded from anywhere else?

Comment: In your browser, go to the HTTPS URL that Java could not access. Click on the HTTPS certificate chain (there is lock icon in the google Chrome) or you can use the certificate from the home page of portal.azure.com on the browser

Comment: @user3632940 - If the above provided answer was helpful ? If so could you please mark the answer as solution . This could help other community users who have similar query in the future